# How to detect and draw contours using OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I wrote the following code to detect and draw contours:

```
img = cv2.imread('test2.tif');

if not img is None:
    imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0);
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    #draw a three pixel wide outline 
    cv2.drawContours(img,contours,-1,(0,255,0),3);
```

And here is the error I received:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:/Users/R.K.singh/Desktop/Image processing/intro-to-contours.py", line 10, in 
>           contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
>       ValueError: too many values to unpack

What is wrong? I am using Python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to emphasize Selchuk's point, the syntax involving OpenCV 3.x has changed a little bit. It has a different return value when it comes to `cv2.findContours`. It returns the following `image, contours, hierarchy`.

Previous versions of OpenCV, however, return only `contours, hierarchy`. They do not return the image.

Answer (score 2):

Change the following line. You are using OpenCV 3.1.0 but you have coded using OpenCV 2.7.x.

```
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE,
      cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Also this [link](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/04/21/building-pokedex-python-finding-game-boy-screen-step-4-6/) will help you.

Comment: what's edged? It isn't defined in my code. @selçuk-İlhan-aydi